# как добавить значение в state array ? react js

Tags: reactjs

есть метод addItem который принимает параметр значение введенные в input , как добавить это значение в state array после нажатие на button

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import List from './List/List'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    cars: [
      {name: 'Ford'},
      {name: 'Audi'},
      {name: 'Mazda'}
    ]
  }

  deleteHandler(index) {
    const { cars } = this.state;
    const newCars = cars.filter((car, idx) => idx !== index);
    this.setState({ cars: newCars });
  }

  addItem(event) {
    let item = {value: event.target.value};
  }

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      textAlign: 'center'
    }

    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>

        { this.state.cars.map((car, index) => {
          return (
            <List
              key = {index}
              name = {car.name}
              onDelete = {this.deleteHandler.bind(this, index)}
            />
          )
        }) }
        <form>
        <label>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.addItem} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте следующий вариант:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import List from './List/List'

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    cars: [
      {name: 'Ford'},
      {name: 'Audi'},
      {name: 'Mazda'}
    ],
    newCar: '',
  }

  deleteHandler(index) {
    const { cars } = this.state;
    const newCars = cars.filter((car, idx) => idx !== index);
    this.setState({ cars: newCars });
  }

  handleChange = e => this.setState({ newCar: e.target.value });

  addItem = () => {
    this.setState({ cars: [...this.state.cars, { name: this.state.newCar}]});
  }

  render() {
    const divStyle = {
      textAlign: 'center'
    }

    return (
      <div style={divStyle}>
        { this.state.cars.map((car, index) => {
          return (
            <List
              key = {index}
              name = {car.name}
              onDelete = {this.deleteHandler.bind(this, index)}
            />
          )
        }) }
        <form>
          <label>
            <input type="text" value={this.state.newCar} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </label>
          <button type="submit" onClick={this.addItem} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте вот таким образом

```
const [dataAction, setDataAction] = useState({name: '', description: ''});

const _handleChangeName = (data) => {
    if(data.name)
        setDataAction( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   name : data.name }));
    if(data.description)
        setDataAction( prevState  => ({ ...prevState,   description : data.description }));
};

....return (

      <input onChange={(event) => _handleChangeName({name: event.target.value})}/>
      <input onChange={(event) => _handleChangeName({description: event.target.value})}/>
)
```